# Trigger jQueryUI datePicker on button click, send result to disabled input field

Tags: jquery-ui, button, triggers, uidatepicker

I've been searching for a way to do this, but could not find anything

I want to have a:

- Disabled input text field, called #XX. This input will store the selected value from datepicker (as this input is disabled I won't be able to use this to trigger the datePicker)
- Button, besides #XX. When user clicks this button, datePicker will show. User will select the date, and this date will be assigned to disabled input #XX.

I want this so user can't change manually -by typing crap- the selected date

Also, should I validate if date was entered using #XX.val()? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            constrainInput: true,
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonText: 'Select...'
        });
    });
</script>
<input id="datepicker" disabled="disabled" />
```

This will add a button next to the input field, and disable the user from entering text into the field...

Answer (score 48):

You can show a datepicker that has been previously attached to an input element using the "show" method.

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {
    $('#myField').datepicker("show");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be to late but I just did this

```
$("#firstDate").datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
        myfunc();
    }
}); 

$("#secondDate").datepicker({
    showOn: ''
}); 

function myfunc(){
    var fDate = $('#firstDate');
    var sDate = $('#secondDate');
    sDate.val(fDate.val());
}
```

It doesn't show the datepicker clicking the input and doesn't display the button to show the datepicker. **Disabled** doesn't work in my case because I need to extract the value from that input field.