# trigger ui datepicker on button click inside gridview and assign selected date to field in current row

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I found this question and solution, however I'm not dealing with a text box, but a gridview field. [Trigger jQueryUI datePicker on button click, send result to disabled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611515/trigger-jqueryui-datepicker-on-button-click-send-result-to-disabled-input-field)

I have a Start Date column in an asp GridView with a TemplateField and if the ImageButton is clicked, I would like to trigger the jquery ui datepicker.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns=False allowsorting = True
        SkinID=FACGrid onload="GridView1_Load" onsorting="GridView1_Sorting" 
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
        onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" 
        onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
        onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>     
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Date" SortExpression="start_dt">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="StDt" runat="server" CssClass="StartDate" Text='<%# Eval("start_dt", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="StDt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("start_dt", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="startdtimage" CssClass="StartDateImg" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/pencil.gif" Visible='<%# HasUpdateStartDateRole() %>' Width="18px" Height="18px" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Based on the above referenced question, I have this.  What do I need to make this work per row?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".ArrivalDate").datepicker();

        $(".StartDateImg").click(function () {
            $(".StartDate").datepicker("show");
        });

    });
</script>
```

There is also a hidden column with the hire date.  I want to set the datepicker to only allow dates equal to or after the hire date.  Or, after the date is selected validate that it doesn't precede the hire date.

**** EDIT ****
Would it be easier to have the imagebutton open a modal dialog and pass the row's start date and hire date to it?  Then have an "update" button to check and save the date.  But, I'm unsure of how to do that as well.

**** EDIT ****
Using @Miki Shah's solution below, the datepicker is displaying, but I don't know how to assign the selected date to the startdate field for that row, use the startdate field for that row as the current selected date when it opens, and use that row's hire_date for validation or for restricting the available dates in datepicker.

Comment: try to remove the double quotes and try to add single qoutes and see in("Show")..

Comment: changing the quotes made no difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign datepicker by classname. Whenever image with "StartDateImg" classname is click, datepicker will show.

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function () {

            $(".StartDateImg").datepicker({
                duration: '',
                showTime: false,
                constrainInput: false,
                onSelect: function(dateText) {$(this).parents().find("span")[0]).innerHTML = dateText; 
            });
     }
```

Comment: The datepicker shows up momentarily, but then the screen refreshes and it's gone.

Comment: means, after page refresh, when click on image button, datepicker is not opening?

Comment: No, I can see the datepicker but before I can do anything the screen refreshes and it's gone.  I can click the image button again and the same thing happens.

Comment: Also, in the brief moment that it showed, it showed the current date as selected.  I would need it to open with the start date selected.

Comment: I think, in your case, Imagebutton does postback, do you need to do postback on imagebutton click? You can take image control, or stop postback for imagebutton by onclientclick=”javascript:return false;”

Comment: The onclientclick stopped the refreshing.  However the start date isn't shown as selected in the datepicker, and the date I select isn't saved to my start date field.

Comment: Should I just do it as a modal dialog instead? But, I don't know how to get that to work either.

Comment: To change selected date of datepicker, you can use following
$('#dateselector').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2008,9,03) );

Comment: So Set Label StartDate to selected date to Datepicker, Please see my code, i have edited "onSelect:" function, and use can check

Comment: Please don’t forget  to click on answer if this is solution

Comment: "To change selected date of datepicker, you can use following $('#dateselector').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2008,9,03) );"  I know how to do that, but I don't know how to get the value of startdate for the row that I'm clicking.  I can't just do $('#startdate').val()  Same for setting it, I need to be able to set it for that row's startdate.

Comment: Use can use jquery selctor to get Label control and set value as selected date. Please see edited code for onselect function onSelect: function(dateText) {$(this).parents().find("span")[0]).innerHTML = dateText;}

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: working in html

I came up with a (not very elegant) solution so it's your call if you can or want to use it or not. :)

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".starter").each(function () {
            $(this).children(".StartDateImg").datepicker().hide();
        });
    });

    $(".starter").each(function () {
        $(this).children(".link").click(function () {
            $(this).nextAll().show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="starter">
    <a class="link" href="#">test</a>
    <div class="StartDateImg">
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem with the datepicker is that it automatically chooses to display inline or as popup.. => inline when applied to a div or span, popup when applied to input/text box

So my solution will load the datepicker inline in a div, hide this div and then show it when the correct link is pressed.

This will just show the div => to get the popup you will have to look into writing some css or javascript to make the div "appear" like a popup.

I hope it helps but I believe a more elegant solution may be found..

Comment: That gives me an error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'settings': object is null or undefined"

Comment: Did you try with or without the "function(){" after ".each("? I forgot to paste it there the first time so I edited the post afterwards..

Comment: Added the function, no error, but the datepicker doesn't show.

Comment: Above answer (where your screen refreshes) could be correct.. Perhaps you should try removing your anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this....
Template column in the gridview will be like this.....

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button Text="calendar" runat="server" CssClass="Calendar"    onclientclick="return Testing();" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The Scripting function should be like this..........

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        function Testing(){
            $('.calendar').each(function () {
                $(this).glDatePicker();
            });
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

Here after selecting a date from the date picker you can observe that value of the button will be change, i.e it shows the date .....
I used button here to invoke the glDatePicker :D Hope it helps you

Comment: I have the same issue with this.  How does it know which row's startdate to save the new value to?  How does it get that row's hire_date for validation?