# hiding/displaying a datepicker on custom button click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

How do I display/hide a date picker only on click on a custom button?

My objective is to disable the functionality of the date picker by hiding it when I click somewhere other than the date picker.

Comment: add some code what you have tried yet.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611515/trigger-jqueryui-datepicker-on-button-click-send-result-to-disabled-input-field
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239457/how-to-show-a-jquery-datepicker-on-button-click

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use [`showOn`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOn) button option, it enable a button near the datepicker.

You can use [`show`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-show) and [`hide`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-hide) datepicker methods in order to toggle the visibility.

In the demo I have blocked the opening/closing anywhere so it's totally handled.

Code:

```
jQuery.datepicker._checkExternalClick = function () {};

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    constrainInput: true,
    showOn: 'none',
    onSelect: function () {
        $(this).data('datepicker').inline = true;
    },
    onClose: function () {
        $(this).data('datepicker').inline = false;
    }
});

$('#toggle').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('hide');
    } else {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('show');
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('opened');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/8wLg92x1/