# Input type date inside a button

Tags: html, date, button

Im trying to create a button and as soon as you click it a input date should pop up. So that you can select a date and move on to the next page.

This far; i cant seem to get the input date popup when i click a button. I did manage to make the button look like a normal date input, but thats not what im looking for.

This looks like this:

```
<button> <input type="date"></input> Submit </button>
```

I have no idea how to deal with this and could not find anything on Google, So thats why i am here.

Comment: So when you click the button you want the Datepicker to open up? Is there any reason for this? Why not use just the datepicker which has the ability to open a calendar?

Comment: First: `<input/>` and not `<input></input>`, second: `type="date"` does not work in FireFox, third: you can't have input inside submit button - it's invalid and also user will not have to enter value, because form will be submitted already.

Comment: Hmmm.. Have you tried using Datepicker? If you use Datepicker you can do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2611555/7271525 Update:
or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20239764/7271525